# How do I load a local .SQL file into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, file-io

I have a 56mb file on my web server, and I would like to (I think) use INFILE to load a filename.SQL file into mysql.

I don't really want to upload it because that will just take too long, but I would like to just use the local file on the system to import into mysql. The file contains the table creation instructions already so I don't need to specify the target, just execute the SQL as is in the file.

Comment: Do you have access to a shell on the server? You need to use the mysql client program to import a sql file.

Comment: `mysql (connection options) < file.sql`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass it in as a stream from the command prompt. Something like this:

```
mysql -u theuser -D thedatabase < filename.SQL
```

Answer (score 4):

login to mysql command line environment and do:

`mysql> source file_name.sql`