# Executing a 120mb insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, file, import

I am trying to run an INSERT statement (from a file.sql - in relation to my post [ [How do I load a local .SQL file into MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629287/how-do-i-load-a-local-sql-file-into-mysql) ]) however the INSERT statement takes up the whole file. It is a single insert statement that is about 120mb in size.

I keep getting this error when running the following command:

Command: mysql -u username -p database < import.sql
Error: ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 28: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I have no idea how to make this work. I have tried adjusting the max packet size values, still no luck.

Comment: How about splitting this up into some smaller chunks?

Comment: That is difficult to do to a file that is 120mb in size (for me at least)

Comment: I did not say it's easy :)


with linux (using e.g. sed and split) it should not be too hard

Comment: How would i do that with sed and split? I am not a linux superstar by any means :)

Comment: I take it that the statement is of the form `insert into table select stuff from some_other_table` (and not multiple repetitions of `insert into table values (blah, etc...)`)?  If so, then I suspect that the main select statement consists of some subqueries.  Create staging tables for those subqueries.

Comment: could you clarify that? Is the file 120MB or is it an INSERT INTO ... SELECT producing around 120MB of data?

Comment: No subqueries or anything. It is like this:

INSERT INTO `TABLENAME` VALUES 
( ...., ...., ..., .... ),
( ...., ...., ..., .... ),
.,
.,
( ...., ...., ..., .... );

Basically a lot of those adding up to about 120MB.

Comment: So you have 60MB of fields and 60MB of data to insert? Or just a few fields with just a LOT of data in one particular field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the `max_allowed_packet parameter` on the *server*.  See [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) for information.

Comment: Jim, I did try that - it did not get rid of the errors. I tried that before posting this question.